# Trying to replace $.live(..) with $.on(..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I've been reading about replacing jQuery `live()` functions with `on()`, but they only work the same way as non-live functions.

For example, using the `$('a').on('click', function(){});` has the same effect as using: `$('a').click(function(){});`

I need to replicate the functionality of `$('a').live('click', function(){});`
because I'm adding elements to the page dynamically.

Comment: Scroll down a bit at the documentation, and you will see the answer...: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a selector:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function(){})
```

Where `#container` is the `id` of the **static** parent of all the relevant anchors.
Try to attach the `on` to the closest static parent.

`on` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> if selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Comment: This method is preferred over the other answers that bound the event onto body/document. By having a more focused element (#container), you operate a little more efficiently. You should bind the $.on to the nearest common parent of all elements that are going to have this event. If that is body, that is okay. But if they are all in a single table, then use that table as the container.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - I was being too hasty it seems. The Docs page for this was very text heavy, and I just wanted a nice quick answer, thanks!

Comment: @Alexcoady. though it might be heavy, You will learn a lot from reading each page of the docs. I did it, suggest you to do the same if you're using jQuery on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of:

```
$('a').live('click', function(){});
```

is this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){});
```

But, `.on()` is more powerful because rather than attach all event handlers to the `document` object like `.live()` does, you can pick a static parent that is much closer to your dynamic objects and will be more efficient, particularly if you have a lot of delegated event handlers.

For example if you had a container div called links, you would do this:

```
$("#links").on('click', 'a', function(){});
```

The selector in the jQuery object is the static object that you want the event handler bound to.  The selector in the arguments to `.on()` is a selector that matches the objects who's events you want to handle that will bubble up to your static parent object.