# Using jQuery .on vs. using .live?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

Simple question, since version 1.7 of jQuery .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on(); however .on() does not seem to work on elements that are rendered via JavaScript and loaded into the DOM. So my question is, should .live() still be used or how would .on() capture these newly generated elements?

As an example, here's my code:

```
$("#listitem").append("<li id='removeitem'>" + 
       formdata + ' <a href="#">Remove</a></li>');
```

And when I try to operate on this element via .on() - the result is nothing, whereas .live() is able to grab this element.

```
$("#removeitem").live("click", function(event) { alert($(this).text()); });
```

Comment: where is code for `.on()` you've tried?

Comment: All you need to know is here: [Differences Between jQuery .bind() vs .live() vs .delegate() vs .on()](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Comment: @thecodeparadox maybe that's my problem - I just replaced .live with .on

Comment: @firedrawndagger. Well... that's won't work for sure...

Comment: I got that and also suggest in answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`live` version:

```
$("#removeitem").live("click", function(event) { alert($(this).text()); });
```

should be changed to:

```
$("#containerId").on("click", "#removeitem", function(event) { 
    alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Where `containerId` is the **static** element that the `removeitem` is loaded into.

You can simply use `body` as the static element:

```
$("body").on('click', '#removeitem'm fn);
```

But the code will be less efficient, just try with it to show how it works.

---

**Notes:**

1. I hope you don't have multiple elements with the same `id` because it's invalid markup.
2. It looks like `listitem` is the static element in your code.

**Update:**

> Maybe that's my problem - I just replaced .live with .on

You can't simply replace them... They work in other ways, and have different parameters!

Read the docs for each function:

[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
.on(events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject))
```

[`live`:](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
.live( events, handler(eventObject) )
```

Comment: Right the id is just something I put here, in reality I have a dynamically generated class that I assign, e.g. "item1", "item2", etc.

Comment: Now what if these are dynamic elements though, in other words I wouldn't know in advance if there were 2 or 5 of them, so how would I write the #removeitem, if it's really more like .removeitem1 and .removeitem2?

Comment: You can use start with selectors like `[class^=removeitem]` which will select all element with classname starting with `removeitem`

Comment: @firedrawndagger. Give all the new elements a class, let's say `item` and use this `$('body').on('click', '.item', handler);`

Comment: But if I just want one of them, e.g. out of a list, only remove the one with class .removeitem3 and leave the others be?

Comment: @firedrawndagger.  then use this as the selector... (one of)the thing(s) about moving from `live` to `on` is the selector of `live` is the second parameter of `on`.

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for the help. I had some issues figuring out the selectors but once i generalized it to the element - <li> and then used $(this) to manipulate it, that made it work

Answer (score 1):

You should try with`.on()`like this:

```
$('#listitem').on('click', '#removeitem', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/118/)**

If you don't have fixed id like `removeitem` and if its structure like `removeitem1`, `removeitem1` etc then try:

```
$('#listitem').on('click', '[id^=removeitem]', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can inform the OP if he didn't comment to your answer.