# jQuery 'change' event handler

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, handler, jquery-events

I am making a file uploader. I am trying to make it so that when one input field is filled it creates a new input field. My issue is in binding the event handler to dynamically created elements. My code can be found at the following URL: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5Az/

If you look in the scripts section at the line indicated, the issue is that the event handler is not actually set here. It does not produce any visible errors or console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok just try this . i have updated your js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5Az/5/

**You have to use the jquery live event that Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.**

Ref site:
[Jquery live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

---

### Update

---

**Live is depreciated so now `on` function will work as live**
[here is the link for ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

this question is updated accordingly to on function 
here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5Az/6/

Comment: Thanks Hameed, I have read about jQuery live, however being new to jQuery I forgot about it almost immediately.

Comment: @undefined do you have any evidence about this ?