# Using JQuery .after method on an element generated by JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have table rows generated by jquery and since they are generated on the fly I would use any selector with .live method to bind events. But after binding my event I want to append more rows so I was using the .after method like this.

```
$("#addItem").live("click", function (e, index) {    
    $('#myTable  tbody > tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + Contenet + '</td></tr'>);
});
```

The problem is the after method doesn't seem to recognize table rows generated by JQuery itself but works just fine when I test it with purely html rows. SO I want to know if there is a method like live where I can use instead of after or any workaround?

Comment: `Live()` is deprecated, use `on ()`

Comment: how do you bind the events?

Comment: Don't forget "+" before and after colons.

Comment: I'm still using jquery 1.8.3 so that is why I'm using live method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

Comment: Oh wait a second, after re-reading your question and tuning up my crystal ball, do you have more than one `#addItem` element in the page? I'm assuming that as otherwise `.live` would make no difference. In that case, it is invalid to have duplicated IDs inside a document.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes that is true and the code above works just fine when I manually insert an HTML row first but when I use another jquery method to insert a row and use the above code it gets me nowhere

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I don't think its a duplicate of that question, like I said above am using JQuery 1.8.3 which still supports .live

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the issue? The problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9 .

If you are using jQuery 1.7 and above you should use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Snippet from jQuery's documentation:

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().**
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. **If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next**.
>
> **Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time**. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example
>   attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:
>
> `$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
>
>   alert($(this).text()); 
>   });`
>
> **A delegated-events approach attaches an
>   event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs
>   to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):**
>
> **`$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
>
>   alert($(this).text());
>   });`**
>
> Note: Delegated events do not work for SVG.

To remove events bound with `.on()`, see [`.off()'](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the append in the TBODY, it will always inject code as the last row

```
$('#myTable  tbody').append('<tr><td>' + Content + '</td></tr'>);
```

If you must have any methods binded to the rows, you could use the delegate events.

Like this:

```
function Method1(oRow)
{
    console.log(oRow);
}
$('#myTable  tbody').on('click','tr',function(){
    Method1(this);
});
```

This will work for every rows inside the tbody, because I setted the tbody as a permanent reference to detect a click.

Comment: Thanks and sure it does, as does after, but the thing is I have unknown number of rows that may or may not be generated by another method in the tbody. So when this rows are generated this methods don't work.

Comment: @altsyset added an example of using "on" method. If you prefer to use live, you should bind it against a element that you have sure that will be in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qjbB7/

HTML:
add

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#add").click(function addRow(){
    $('#myTable  tbody > tr:last').after('<tr><td>text</td></tr>');
});
```