# apply jquery on page loaded in div later say in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario which is

Index.jsp, included a js file say temp.js, 10 data coming from backend as JSON and in jquery I am creating anchor tag with onclick property
    object = []

```
(for i=0;i<10;i++)
 object = new Object();
  //setting the different attributes of this object and passing index to the onclick function
 <a href="modal.jsp" onClick(i) ></a>
```

And Onclick is opening the bootstrap modal and in a bootstrap modal div.say #actionModal in Index.jsp and the body of modal is written in modal.jsp

modal.jsp contain a form which i have to fill after clicking of respective anchor tag generated in the index.jsp page and I have data associated with it.

Now If I want to fill all the form in modal.jsp I have to call this temp.js again then only jquery can fill elements of forms accessing Id.As It is loaded after the execution of erlier js file.
But I don't want to do that.
What is the best way to achieve this scenario.

I hope I made my doubt clear to everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a few times.

Use jquery on() function.

[jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

http://api.jquery.com/on/