# Jquery fadeToggle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I need to fadeToggle some classes when I am hover on image. I am using Opencart.
Here is how it works https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7dCu.jpg
As you can see it works, but when I click to the **List** or **Grid**(top right) the effect is not working.
**Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".image").hover(function(){
  $(".wishlist, .compare").fadeToggle();
 });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
 <div class="image">    
   <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo   $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
   </a>
    <div class="wishlist" style="display: none;"style="display: none;"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="ebenicon ebenicon-plus-square"></i><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>
  <div class="compare" style="display: none;">
    <a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo    $product['product_id']; ?>');">
   <i class="ebenicon ebenicon-plus-square"></i><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but I assume you want to have your image 'fadeOut' when you hover?

Do you necessarily want to use jQuery, as I can imagine you can simply CSS for this. Although, I do not see any problems in your code.. Anyway, try one of these examples below.

```
.image:hover > .wishlist, .image:hover > .compare {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If you really want to use jQuery, try this.

```
$( ".image" ).mouseOver(function() {
  $(this).find(".compare").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
  $(this).find(".wishlist").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
    // fading complete.
  });
});
$( ".image" ).mouseOut(function() {
  $(this).find(".compare").fadeTo( "fast" , 1.0, function() {
  $(this).find(".wishlist").fadeTo( "fast" , 1.0, function() {
    // back to normal.
  });
});
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, but this should fade `.wishlist` and `.compare` to 50% opacity.

Comment: No, still it doesn't work. `.wishlist` and `.compare` are still shown.

Comment: With those pieces of code added, could you please check what the developer console in Chrome reports? What bugs there are?

Answer (score 1):

the reason being when you click on `List/Grid` some html is regenerated(replaced) by js function `display()` around line 112 in `category.tpl`

so in this function you got `if else` conditional block for `list or grid` view, so it regenerates   some html including `compare and wishlist div` at around line 119 and 183, so you need to add `style="display:none"` there also

change this (in both if and else)

```
html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';
```

to

```
html += '<div style="display:none" class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
html += '<div style="display:none" class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';
```

also why are you adding `style="display:none"` two times in `wishlist` div ?

-- **Edit**

one more error, to make `hover` on dynamically created element you have to use it little differently, also `hover` is deprecated  so use `on` like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('hover','.image',function(){
  $(".wishlist, .compare").fadeToggle();
 });
});
```

reference : [jQuery .on function for future elements, as .live is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)

Comment: That was mistake, but still it doesn't work(when I corrected that mistake). Before I click on `List` or `Grid` it works, but when I click on `List` the `.wishlist` and `.compare` are shown no fadeToggle().

Comment: @ViktorR have you added the code i gave you above ?

Comment: Yes, I have to the both(`List/Grid`)

Comment: @ViktorR i can't understand what you mean to say. your css was already messed up as one can see from your earlier gif in the question. if you apply these changes to a fresh default theme they work fine. whatever weird is happening is due to your messed up styling like add to cart button flying somewhere etc.