# Sequentially click links attached with ajax events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On the popular social media site [reddit.com](http://reddit.com) there's a feature where you can load more comments. I realize that comments are hidden for performance reasons, but I would like to expand all comments so I don't have to manually do so. The problem is you can only activate one link at a time, or they will all say 'loading...' I have tried using setTimeout and setInterval and so on. Here's a naive attempt that freezes the page:

```
while ($(".morecomments a:contains('load more comments')").length)
{
    $(".morecomments a").first().click();
}
```

Is there a way to have this "run in the background" (so it doesn't interrupt browsing and other javascript events) and click on each link once it is done loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery "on()" method to bind click events, see following links

[jQuery On](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

[Jquery on function for future elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated)