# jQuery not executing code for new element with new id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image, and when I click on it I want it to change to a different image and change its ID as well. Then when I click on this new image, it reverts back.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name_edit").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", "img/tick.png");
        $(this).attr("id","name_confirm");
    });
    $("#name_confirm").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", "img/edit.png");
        $(this).attr("id","name_edit");
    });
});
```

I have successfully done the first step, going from #name_edit to #name_confirm. However, not the reverse.

How do I go about solving this?

My suspicion is that since I'm using (document).ready, jQuery is preparing itself for elements already on the page. However, the element with the ID name_confirm does not exist until the image is clicked on.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Your suspicion is correct. Place both bindings, one for "name_edit" and one for "name_confirm" in separate functions (call them init_name_edit, for example). Call these functions at the end of .click function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element that you are working on is always the same...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // use just the first id value to find it in the DOM
    $("#name_edit").click(function(){
      var item = $(this);
      var id = item.attr('id');
      
      if(id === 'name_edit') {
        return item
          .attr("src", "img/tick.png")
          .attr("id","name_confirm")
        ;
      }
    
      
      return item
        .attr("src", "img/edit.png")
        .attr("id","name_edit")
      ;
    })
    ;
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. And yes, I did make a small mistake in my title, the element itself is the same, only thing changing is the ID. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have chosen bad solution for your problem.
1) Why your code doesn't work:
You bind 2 events only 1 time, whne your document loaded. So, jquery finds #name_edit element and bind onclick event on it. But jquery cannot find #name_confirm element, because it doesn't exists on document ready)
In your code you should bind 1 onclick event, but have some attr (for example class for checking your state).
Something like:

```
 <img id="main_image" class="name_edit"/>
 <script>
 var img_paths = ["img/tick.png", "img/edit.png"]
 var img_index = 0;
 $("#main_image").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("class") == "name_edit"){
       $(this).attr("src", "img/tick.png");
       $(this).attr("class","name_confirm"); 
    }
    else{   
       $(this).attr("src", "img/edit.png");
       $(this).attr("class","name_edit");
    }
 });
 </script>
```

2. Other solutions: You can create 2 images and show/hide them.
   Or use styles with background attr. With pseudoclasses or classes.
   Also you can store image pathes in array and tick array index on click.

Something like:

```
 var img_paths = ["/content/img1.png", "/content/img2.png"]
 var img_index = 0;
 $("#main_image").click(function(){
    $(this).src = img_paths[img_index];
    img_index = !img_index;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are referencing the same elements, try this:

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined){
  $("#name_edit").on("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.attr("id") === "name_edit") {
      self.attr("src", "img/tick.png");
      self.attr("id", "name_confirm");
    } else {
      self.attr("src", "img/edit.png");
      self.attr("id", "name_edit");
    }
  });
})(this, this.document, jQuery);
```

Also for easier to understand code you could use classes like this:

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined){
  $(".name_edit").on("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.hasClass("name_edit")) {
      self.attr("src", "img/tick.png");
      self.removeClass("name_edit").addClass("name_confirm");
    } else {
      self.attr("src", "img/edit.png");
      self.removeClass("name_confirm").addClass("name_edit");
    }
  });
})(this, this.document, jQuery);
```

To simplify replacing classes you could even add your own `$.fn.replaceClass();` like this:

```
jQuery.fn.replaceClass = function(classA, classB) {
  this.removeClass(classA).addClass(classB);
  return this;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined){
  $(".name_edit").on("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.hasClass("name_edit")) {
      self.attr("src", "img/tick.png");
      self.replaceClass("name_edit", "name_confirm");
    } else {
      self.attr("src", "img/edit.png");
      self.replaceClass("name_confirm", "name_edit");
    }
  });
})(this, this.document, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what the others said.. the jquery gets run on document ready, but doesn't get updated subsequently - so it basically gets the correct element from the dom, and assigns the click event. It has no event for the name_confirm.

so this code does nothing...

```
$("#name_confirm").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "img/edit.png");
    $(this).attr("id","name_edit");
});
```

[See it not work in this instructive jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mno60qmn/)

Of course does the id need to change? is it possible to use for example a specific class for the img? then you could make the second click bind on the class instead... for example see [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9g9es57j/), which still changes the src and id...

Answer (score -2):

Try On method:

```
$(document).on('click', '#name_edit', function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "img/tick.png");
    $(this).attr("id","name_confirm");
});
$(document).on('click', '#name_confirm', function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "img/edit.png");
    $(this).attr("id","name_edit");
});
```

Comment: The problem is that `$('#name_confirm')` doesn't exists yet when you try to bind the click event. (`.on('click')` and `.click()` are the same functions, the second one is just an alias).

Comment: Nope, they're not the same functions. `on` binds events of the future elements as well which is the case here. It was previously named as `live` which is deprecated now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated

Comment: you are misunderstanding it with the event delegation that you can obtain using a `filter selector` but you need to bind with its container and not with the element itself. `$('#name_confirm')` returns an empty jQuery collection.

Comment: your last edit makes more sense but isn't good in term of performances because you need to delegate the click event to the whole document object. Plus, if there's some `event.stopPropagation()` in the propagation chain you lost that event. Event delegation should be used only when you can't do something in another and more performant way.