# Sweet alert redirects before the user clicks OK

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm using SweetAlert2 and want to redirect the user to a different page, BUT after the success alert and the user clicks OK.

this one:

```
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function() {
        swal(
          'Deleted!',
          'Your file has been deleted.',
          'success'
        );
    });
```

like this:

```
function deleteEvent(id)
{
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'You will not be able to recover this event!',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then(function() {
        swal(
          'Deleted!',
          'Your event has been deleted.',
          'success'
        );
            $.ajax({
                url: '/events/'+id,
                type: "DELETE",
                data:{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" },
                success: function() {
                    location.href = '/events';
                }
            });
    });
}
```

But when the user clicks the confirm button to delete....this popup
[image]

goes right away because of my redirect and the user doesn't even get the chance to click the OK button...

How can i make the redirect AFTER the user clicks the OK on this image?

Comment: sorry that I am unable to reproduce the above issue in 7th example. works fine for me

Comment: yes, the example is fine but in my code this is the problem `success: function() {
                    location.href = '/events';
                }` it goes straight away when user click the yes delete it on first pop up....and this image that i posted with green checkmark is gone almost immediatelly. user doesn't get a chance to click it at all...because it redirects the page header. I want to redirect after the user clicks OK button

Comment: Ok remove ajax call from the function, add an Event Listener (using .on , which works for dynamic elements ) on the OK button, and try redirecting. Hope this helps

Comment: But i don't have access to this OK button it's implemented in sweet alert :(

Comment: add an event listener to $('.sweet-container .confirm') - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated

Comment: I don't know what you meant but this is the right solution for me -> see the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved this on my own:

```
function deleteEvent(id)
{
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'You will not be able to recover this event!',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/events/'+id,
            type: "DELETE",
            data:{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" }
        }).done(function() {

            swal({
                title: "Deleted", 
                text: "Event has been successfully deleted", 
                type: "success"
            }).then(function() {
                location.href = '/events';
            });
        });
    });
}
```