# jQuery .on not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, mouseover

I've written the following piece of code following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191064/jquery-on-function-for-future-elements-as-live-is-deprecated) suggestion.

```js
if (window.jQuery) {
  jQuery("document").on('mouseenter', 'div', function(event) {
    alert(jQuery(this).text());
  });
  alert("ok");
} else {
  alert("no!")
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
</body>
```

Why does no alert box appear?

Comment: I would start by moving the `<script>` to before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: *JSFiddle snippet here. Why does no alert box appear* :) I need another coffee now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `$("document")` (I mean `<document>`) element in your page, but a `document DOM object` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document)) therefore you need:

```
$(document)
```

> without the ""

Also, place ideally the `<script>` tag **before** the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- SCRIPT GOES (ideally) HERE -->
</body>
```

Another place to put `script` tags is inside `<head>`. Just don't use it mixed within your HTML like in the middle of the page... - or it will pause document parsing and act as render-blocking (since the JS engine will kick-in trying to see what you desired).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was - jQuery("document"). You cannot have document with quotes.

Try this -

```js
if (window.jQuery) {
$(document).on('mouseenter','div',function(event){alert(jQuery(this).text());});
alert("ok");
}
else {alert("no!")}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>aaa</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok I edited that and added the problem as well. But I answered your question before it was accepted as the solution by you. Thanks