# jQuery could not get modal input value

Tags: jquery, wordpress

From a shortcut visual composer modal gallery  i would like to get an input value from a modal and put it into another one in the same modal.
[gallery_short_cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C5lj.jpg)

[galllery_short_cut_inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72sFe.jpg)

i could not get access to inputs value , i test if the page contains the modal an alert will appear . the problem that inputs are shown in the navigator inspector if modal is opened .
is there any way to get the input values.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery(".wpb_element_wrapper")[0]) {
        alert("hello world"); 
    }              
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the html of the element you are targeting. Visual composer is going to generate dynamic elements, you should add the code from the resultant website post saving the visual composer.

Answer (score 0):

Probable Cause: You have defined jQuery function on an element that yet doesn't exist on the page. So the function exists but hasn't bind to any element.

Probable Solution:
You could bind the function on the element that could come in future too, e.g.

```
$("body").on("change", ". wpb_element_wrapper", function(){
    $(".other_input_class").val($(this).val());
});
```

Further read: You can refer to [jquery's on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191450/1320407).

Comment: when the modal is loaded , i would that the input with class .ids get a static text for example , id doesn't get it

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function( ){
      jQuery("body").on("change", ".wpb_element_wrapper", function(){
   jQuery(".ids").val("testt");
});
 

          
});

Comment: either , i test if the specified element is focused :

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function( ){
   jQuery(".ids").focus(function(){
     alert("test");
    });
});

Comment: is `wpb_element_wrapper` the input element? also to answer your `when the modal is loaded` you could do, $('#my-modal').on('shown', function(){
  $(".ids").val("test");
}); where my-modal is the id of the modal you opened.

Comment: i have revirified with changin css modal color by inspector  , its id is vc_ui-panel-edit-element .

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function( ){
  
jQuery('#vc_ui-panel-edit-element').on('shown', function(){ alert("test") });
});  doesn't work

Comment: `#vc_ui-panel-edit-element` this is probably the id of the edit element inside the visual composer and probably something you might not be able to control. You could add your `id="my-modal"` attribute to the modal, and the use `$('#my-modal').on('shown', function(){ $(".ids").val("test"); });` Should work.

Comment: yes i show the file id="vc_ui-panel-edit-element" when i modified the id , of course modal could not  be opened

Comment: solved  by adding only where ids and imgs are input on the modal :                                                      jQuery(window).click(function() {
   
  jQuery(".ids").val(jQuery(".imgs").val()); 
    
});